# Xamarin Android app not working on arm-64

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I recently moved my Android Studio project into Xamarin. The project uses a few native libraries that are built for `armeabi-v7a`.

The apk built from Android Studio works fine on arm-64 devices (Nexus 9). However, when I deploy Xamarin-built apk to Nexus 9, it doesn't work.

Both the apks work fine on 32-bit devices.

I guess there is something built into Gradle-generated apks such that if `arm64-v8a` shared libraries are not found, it automatically falls back to `armeabi-v7a` shared libraries.

Is there some setting on Xamarin project that can be tweaked to mimic this behavior? Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Xamarin, but I had some similar problem in the past, there are 2 possible workarounds.

1 - By using System.load() instead of System.loadLibrary(), you can specify the filename of the shared library to load explicitly.

2 - If you put your 32-bit libraries into the arm64-v8a folder, the application will load them anyway.

But if Xamarin loads other 64-bit libraries before that, both workarounds will fail.